# Schedule Task created using DSC, not able assign USERS group for running the task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, dsc

```
                        TaskName = 'EXCEL-Auto'
            TaskPath = '\CustomTasks'
            ActionExecutable = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft 
                                            Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft  
                                            Shared\Office16\operfmon.exe'
            
            ScheduleType = 'AtLogOn'
                        #ExecuteAsCredential = 'USERS'
            #BuiltInAccount = 'Users'
            
            RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable = $False
            Enable = $True
            #RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable = $False
            RunOnlyIfIdle = $False
            Priority = '7'
            Hidden = $False
            RestartOnIdle = $False
            AllowStartIfOnBatteries = $True
                        DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries = $True
            Ensure = 'Present'
            DontStopOnIdleEnd = $True
            MultipleInstances = 'IgnoreNew'
                        StartWhenAvailable = $True
```

I am trying to create Schedule Task using DSC and for "Running the action,use following user account" I wanted to Choose USERS instead of SYSTEM (Which is default). I tried changing it like the above code (Line commented). That does not work. any other thoughts?
[Schedule Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa25r.png)

User group like this
[USER Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgoRZ.png)

Comment: I believe you have to provide the username and password when using `ExecuteAsCredential`: `New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'USERNAME', ('PASSWORD' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)`

Comment: Thanks Ab!  
Pls note, I do not want to use any particular userid/pwd. I want to assign the default group called "USERS". Please refer to my attached pic, where by default, it is assigned as "SYSTEM"